# Python telethon get message media file name

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I have the following code to get messages from group:

```
getmessage = client.get_messages(dialog, limit=1000)
for message in getmessage:
    try:
        if message.media == None:
            print("message")
            continue
        else:
            print("Media**********")
            client.download_media(message)
```

The code above write the media.

I need to know the file name/file type before I write the file, How can I get it?

Comment: what do you mean before you write the file ? did you mean before downloading the file ?

Comment: @painor yes, I just want to choose my file name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a filename of your choosing to ensure that said filename will be used:

```py
filename = 'some-file'
filename = client.download_media(message, filename)
```

Then `filename` will be `some-file` with the correct extension.

Otherwise, Telethon will generate a file name for the file (it will try the original name, and if it exists, append `(n)` to avoid overwriting existing files), so you can't really know where it will be saved beforehand (but the method does return the final filename).

Comment: is it possible to choose directory also? I mean ```filename= 'c:\\some-dir\\some-file'``` should work?

Comment: btw, Is is possible to get the file before I write it? I want to filter some file types

Comment: Yes, you can use a directory. Yes, you can check the file type before downloading.

Comment: how? because i see some messages without ```mime_type```, so how can I get the file name before I write it?